# Tengo un error con un modulo el cual no puedo utilizar

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, aplicación-web

Buenas hace tiempo vengo programando en python y quize dar mi paso hacia el mundo del desarrollo web, siguiendo un tutorial para poder crear un blog me encuentro con el problema de no me deja iniciar el servidor tras importar el modulo "Django-import-export"

- class CategoriaResource(resources.ModelResources):
  AttributeError: module 'import_export.resources' has no attribute 'ModelResources'

Instale el modulo pero a la hora de importarlo en pycharm no me sale como si estuviese instalado si no que con una sublinea roja

````
from .models import *
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


class CategoriaResource(resources.ModelResources):
    class Meta:
        model = Categoria

class CategoriaAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["Nombre"]
    list_display = ("nombre", "estado", "fecha_creacion",)
    resource_class = CategoriaResource

class AutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["nombres", "apellidos", "correo"]
    list_display = ("nombres", "apellidos", "correo", "estado", "fecha_creacion")
admin.site.register(Categoria, CategoriaAdmin)
admin.site.register(Autor, AutorAdmin)```

Agradecería su ayuda ya que venia con un buen ritmo y me encuentro atorado sin saber como solucionarlo, desde ya muchas gracias.
````

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución, tuve que instalar el `django-import-export` desde la raíz del disco C

Answer (score 0):

Si te encuentras utilizando Pycharm te sugiero que utilices la opción de los entornos virtuales la cual tiene muy buena integración y te permitirá manejar mas fácilmente los paquetes. Ese IDE es muy bueno en su versión Professional ya que cuenta con una super integración con Django y así no tendrás que instalar los paquetes en tu raíz del C ya que al instalarlo ahí te puede llegar a dar problemas ya que no siempre se tienen los permisos para acceder directo al disco principal.